# ES6 Arrow function: why "this" points differently when used in constructor and object literal?

Tags: javascript, constructor, this, arrow-functions, object-literal

I know that arrow functions inherit `this` from enclosing scope. Yet, still can't understand why `this` in arrow function defined in object literal points to global object, while in constructor to created object. 
Consider following code:

```
function Obj() {
  this.show = () => {
    console.log(this);
  };
}
const o = new Obj();
const o2 = {
  show: () => {
    console.log(this);
  }
}

o.show(); // o
o2.show() // window || undefinded
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function Obj() {
  this.show = () => {
    console.log(this);
  };
}
const o = new Obj();
o.show();
```

Here "this" works based on the rules of the "new" keyword, pointing to a new object with the structure defined inside Obj() (the new object is the context). 
More info at : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new

```
const o2 = {
  show: () => {
    console.log(this);
  }
}
o2.show() // window || undefinded
```

Here "this" gets its value at runtime and because neither lambda functions nor object literals define a context, the context remaining is the global one and that is why you get that value.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found the answer, as stated in "Secrets of the javascript ninja":

> Arrow functions don't have their
>   own context. Instead, the context is inherited
>   from the function in which they’re defined.

So inside constructor function `this === {}`.
While, when defining object literal `this` still points to global object or `undefined` if in strict mode.

Answer (score 1):

That's because at the time of declaration the `Object` is not initialized yet. You can force initialization by using an immediately invoked function expression ([IIFFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)) or use `Object.create`. Something like:

```js
// IIFE
const x = (() => ({a: 1, b: 2, sum() {return this.a + this.b}}))();
console.log(`x.sum() => ${x.sum()}`);
// Object.create
const y = Object.create({a:1, b:2, sum() {return this.a + this.b}});
console.log(`y.sum() => ${y.sum()}`);
```